# Update UI on android after async call

Tags: java, android, android-activity, asynchronous, android-asynctask

I want to update let's say a `TextView's` content after and `Async` call to my server using loopj's `android-async-http` `library`. So my "client" code:

```
    public class AsyncClient {
      private static final String BASE_URL = "http://my.server.com";

      private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

      public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
          client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
      }

      private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
          return BASE_URL + relativeUrl;
      }
}
```

My client's request method is:

```
   class AsyncClientRequests {
        public void getData() throws JSONException {

            AsyncClient.get("/data", null, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // Update UI according to response <<<<-----
            }

        });
    }
}
```

My question is, how can I update my `TextView` if I don't have any `Activity` instance in the "getData" method? I can't use `findViewById()` method, to get the TextView and set it's text.

My only idea is to make an Observer for it with a static list of the Observed Activities.

After this, make my activity observed in the `onCreate()` (unobserved in the onDestroy) and after the `async` call use the static methods (which i can reach from the onSuccess method, maybe make my observer a `singleton` too) to notify the object of getting updated.

I don't think btw this is an acceptable method, because of the conflicts in the static list of observed objects. (not sure if it can happen, im really new in the android world :) )

Can you suggest me something better approach, or more "android like", or i should go with this and hope it will work?

Comment: Can you have your activity implement an interface and register itself so that you hang onto that object and can call a method of the interface to update it?  Note that this is distinct from threading issues, where you either need something like runOnUiThread, the onPostExecute of an AsyncTask, or to use a Handler to push to the UI thread.

Comment: I have no commitment of how I implement my activity if you meant that, but i don't really understand, how can I register and reach my Activity object with implementing that interface?

Comment: Define an interface with a notification method and have your activity implement it.  Have your activity call this other thing and pass its own instance ("this").  Have your code save that as an object of the interface type.  Then when you want to update the activity, see if that object is non-null and if so call a method in the interface to notify it.

Comment: So you are saying when I call that async method, pass my Activity object to the "getData(this)" method, store as a static "MyActivity" and update after the call is successful through a static object? Maybe im wrong but don't understand how else can I reach the object in the new JsonHttpResponseHandler(){ "here" }
It would make things soo much easier if I could pass the Activity object to "new JsonHttpResponseHandler()" and store like "caller" or someting :)

Comment: I'd try to avoid the static storage.  Can you subclass JsonHttpResponseHandler and add an instance field (and constructor argument) to your version to keep track of who to give the result to?

Comment: Well... that just came into my mind typing my last comment. :) Did that and it's working like a charm! Thanks for the help!